# VS Code cannot run SFDX commands from palette

Tags: salesforcedx

When trying to authorize an org using the VS Code palette I get an error saying that permission is denied

If I try the same using the terminal with the command

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --instanceurl=...
```

It displays the same error. However, If I add sudo at the beginning it works

```
sudo sfdx force:auth:web:login --instanceurl=...
```

I presume this is a permission issue to execute the command, so Visual Studio might be attempting to run it as the current user and not as root.

I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling Salesforce CLI with both npm and the package installer, but none of these worked.

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's dangerous to use sudo to run software like sfdx. sfdx might have created files as root (even below your home directory), which are thereafter inaccessible or not writeable to anything run by your regular user - log files, configs, all the other output etc. I'd probably `cd ~ && sudo find .sfdx/ -user root` for a starter. (Was this directory removed during reinstallation?!) I guess the "permission denied" errors are not from Salesforce, but from your Linux?!

Comment: I'm using a macOS Monterey. If files were created as root, then should I change the owner ?

Comment: I'd first check their provenance and make sure they are supposed to be owned by your regular user. If so - yes, I would adjust owner and potentially the group!