# Permission Denied SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, node.js

When I run any SFDX command I get the following error. I looked everywhere but I'm not sure which solution is applicable in this case.

```
(node:3778) [EACCES] Error Plugin: sfdx-cli: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/dk/.sf/sf.log'
module: @oclif/config@1.18.3
task: runHook init
plugin: sfdx-cli
root: /Users/dk/.local/share/sfdx/client/7.157.0-adf40ea
See more details with DEBUG=*
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
sfdx-cli/7.157.0 darwin-x64 node-v16.15.1
```

sudo seems to be working but I'm not sure what changed, this was working fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/376414/vs-code-cannot-run-sfdx-commands-from-palette)? (Apologies for citing myself...) The only difference here is the directory .sf , possibly.

Answer (score 0):

Faced as well with the error message "EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/user/.sf/sf.log'". I assume something changed with default permissions when Apple releases security updates.

So you don't have sufficient permissions to write to the specified file. To fix this issue on macOS, you can try the following steps:

Open Terminal and navigate to the directory where the file is located .

Run the following bash command to change the ownership of the file to your user account:

```
sudo chown $(whoami) /Users/{your_user}/.sf/sf.log
```

Run the following command to change the permissions on the file so that your user account has write access:
bash

```
chmod u+w /Users/{your_user}/.sf/sf.log
```

Try running the sfdx deploy command again in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

(installed Intel version on mac)

Manually deleting the log files, directories, and the cache in Library* fixed this specific error for me. I also went with NVM to install node and latest npm (which was not too obviously recommended in the docs and release notes)

Basically it was trying to write to the log file but had some permission issues.